# What kind of attack is C stack protector effective against?

Tags: c, gcc, stack, clang

I notice gcc and clang inserting __stack_chk_fail@plt in my code. I'm not sure if it's my distro adding them in or if they are the default of newer gcc/clang. I was curious and read the assembly

It appears a thread local variable is written into an invisible 8byte variable on the stack. At the end of the function it checks if the variable still equals the thread local value and if it doesn't it jumps past the `ret` and calls `__stack_chk_fail@plt` which seems to write a message and aborts.

Is my understanding correct? For a moment I thought this would catch off by one mistakes but noticed if the array is char I'd have to be off by 9. Is this a better than nothing solution or is this effective against anything? I tried adding variables before and after the stack but it seems like the invisible variable is always located 8 bytes higher than the array

Comment: It's to protect against buffer overflows smashing the return address.

Comment: ^ I accept this comment as an answer